# "Access violation writing location" when writing to file

Tags: c, file, pointers

So when I'm trying to write to the file I get an error for **Access violation writing location** and the values from the **int** array don't transfer well to the `solve` function as far as I can see.

```
void read(int n, int* v);
int prime(int);
void solve(int n, int x, int* v, FILE*);
void open_file_write(char*, FILE*);

void main()
{
    int n, i, x, k, *v;
    FILE* fp = NULL;
    char s[30];
    n = 7;
    open_file_write(s, fp);
    v = new int[n];
    read(n, v);
    x = v[n / 2];
    solve(n, x, v, fp);
    delete[](v);
    if (fp)
        fclose(fp);
    else exit(1);
}

void solve(int n, int x, int* v, FILE* fp)
{
    int i, k = 0;
    float ma = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (v[i] < x && prime(v[i]))
        {
            printf_s("%d ", v[i]);
            k++;
            ma += v[i];
            fprintf_s(fp, "%d   ", v[i]);
        }
    printf_s("\n%f  ", ma / k);

}


void read(int n, int* v)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf_s("%d", &v[i]);
}


int prime(int x)
{
    int i;
    if ((!(x % 2) && x != 2) || x == 1 || x == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (x == 2)
        return 1;
    for (i = 3; i * i < x; i++)
    {
        if (!(x % i))
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}


void open_file_write(char* file_name, FILE* fp)
{
    errno_t err;
    printf_s("Enter the name of your destination file: ");
    scanf_s("%s", file_name, 100);

    if ((err = fopen_s(&fp, file_name, "w") != 0))   //opening destination file
    {
        puts("Error opening destination file");
        _getch();
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `open_file_write` assigns to the local variable. `fp` in `main` is still `NULL`.

Comment: You tell `scanf_s` that `file_name` buffer is 100 characters large, but in fact it's only 30 characters large. `scanf_s` pads the buffer with zeros, whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of buffer overflow.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik so I should use *&fp,right?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The buffer from scanf_s was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

"You tell scanf_s that file_name buffer is 100 characters large, but in fact it's only 30 characters large. scanf_s pads the buffer with zeros, whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of buffer overflow." -- @Igor Tandetnik